# Deprecated NameValuePair

Tags: android

Here is my Code which shows Deprecate `NameValuePair`, `BasicNameValuePair`, `HttpParams`, `HttpClient`, `DefaultHttpClient`, `HttpPost`, UrlEncodedFormEntity

How to solve this problem..?

Code snippet below

```
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> dataTosend = new ArrayList<>();
        dataTosend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image" , encodedImage));
        dataTosend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name" , name));


        HttpParams httpRequestParams = getHttpRequestParams();

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpRequestParams);
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(SERVER_ADDRESS + "savepicture.php");

        try{
            post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(dataTosend));
            client.execute(post);
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }


}
```

Comment: `HttpClient` is deprecated that means it is no longer maintained by Google. You can switch to `HttpUrlConnection` or much better if you use `Retrofit`.

Comment: @M.WaqasPervez brother i am beginner so be specific and as easy as possible that how to overcome this problem

Answer (score 0):

From Android6.0 its removed, If you want to use that, then add this in your build.gradle

```
android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
```

But try to use `HttpUrlConnection`, see the [official doc](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-apache-http-client)

> Android 6.0 release removes support for the Apache HTTP client. If
>   your app is using this client and targets Android 2.3 (API level 9) or
>   higher, use the HttpURLConnection class instead. This API is more
>   efficient because it reduces network use through transparent
>   compression and response caching, and minimizes power consumption. To
>   continue using the Apache HTTP APIs, you must first declare the
>   following compile-time dependency in your build.gradle file:

Or you can use [volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html) or [retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/)

Comment: I am beginner can you please tell how to replace this code with HttpUrlConnection 
            HttpParams httpRequestParams = getHttpRequestParams();

            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpRequestParams);
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(SERVER_ADDRESS + "savepicture.php");

Comment: yeah !! Actualy seriously i dont know what to do but i want my code to run

Comment: @NabEelKambOh I added in [gist](https://gist.github.com/rmkrishna/a3640c9b6daeae3f981138b67d0eee7f) both class and example, If you have query let me know